# InstallDate00 NULL for a number of programs in v_Add_Remove_Programs

Tags: sccm

I notice that several important programs listed in v_Add_Remove_Programs have a NULL install date, even though the install date exists in Programs and Features on the machine.

How does SCCM collect this data and why would it be null for random programs?

Comment: it should be a direct inventory of HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall (a combination of the 32 and 64bit one) so this key would be a inventory of the InstallDate key there. Can you check if that is also populated on the machine in question?

Comment: Yes, I see the InstallDate key exists for the entry under HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

Comment: That's really strange, I can't think of a reason why this one key would not be inventoried correctly. The only thing that I noticed when I checked in my own environment is that it might be a little confusing that displayname0 is not a unique key here so there might be multiple rows. ProdID0 is the unique key that corresponds to the registry keys name and not some reg_sz, but I assume you noticed that